Look behind you
My aunt observed today that we don't use the reflexive when we say "Look behind you!" or "Walk straight ahead of you." One might indeed expect it; it seems to have the requisite conditions for the reflexive. And in fact some common collocations with prepositions do use it, e.g. "Look within yourself" or "to be beside oneself".
Has any reason been identified for this discrepancy?

I would challenge the premise that yourself is reflexive in those constructions; I’d say it’s emphatic rather than reflexive. The two can be difficult to separate in English, but the fact that we sometimes do also use the -self forms in the same constructions in more or less free variation with the plain forms (I would not blink at ‘he looked behind himself’) is a good indicator that it’s emphatic. Even so, there is clearly a construction-based difference: ‘Look ahead of you’ is fine, but †‘[don’t] get ahead of you’ is completely ungrammatical.

@JanusBahsJacquet Good point about the free variation.

@JanusBahsJacquet Wouldn't you expect sentence-level stress if the forms were emphatic? Also, coreference with the subject seems required (*Look behind myself!).

@TKR Well, coreference with the subject is always required with -self forms, regardless of whether it’s reflexive or emphatic, so I don’t think that makes a difference here. I’d say there is sentence-level stress in cases like ‘he looked behind himself’ and ‘look within yourself’; the stress falls on the PP as a whole (and thus primarily on the preposition), but it is there. But then it’s also there in many reflexive uses (e.g., unstressed he 'gave it to him vs stressed he 'gave it to himˈself), so I’m not sure stress is a reliable litmus test.

I don't think a person can look behind him/herself.  I think a person can look at the area or place or space behind themselves. And I think your aunt is right:  Look behind you [before changing lanes or to find something], which  is also an implied area. Look behind me/him, etc.  and you'll see the [noun]. Your other examples are metaphors.

@JanusBahsJacquet Coreference with subject isn't required for emphatics, e.g. I met the Pope himself. And I think emphatics are always stressed in English (the emphatics themselves, not something else in their phrase). Intuitively I don't see anything emphatic about He was beside himself or Look within yourself -- unless, in the second case, if yourself is stressed, which supports the idea that when unstressed it isn't emphatic (otherwise the contrast wouldn't be meaningful). The contrastive pragmatics of emphatics don't seem to be present there.

It's an interesting question, in any case. I wonder if there's a kind of transitivity-hierarchy phenomenon where the non-reflexive form can be licensed for low-transitivity actions, in this case ones that don't affect the subject=object. So "Take care of yourself/*you" (affected) vs. "Look behind yourself/you" (unaffected). I don't know if this pans out. (Admittedly it would predict "I was beside myself/me" as both grammatical but arguably that's a set idiomatic expression rather than a productive use.)

I'd like to see evidence that "Look behind yourself" is idiomatic in English.

@TKR Emphatic is perhaps not the best label, since actual emphasis can always be added with stress. Disambiguative is probably better, as the purpose is to disambiguate that the pronoun refers to the subject, not someone else. You’re right that when postmodifying a noun inside an NP, there’s no requirement for subject coreference (and that this position is incompatible with reflexives, which can only be pronominal). But when makes up its own NP, both disambiguatives and reflexives do require subject coreference (e.g., neither *I shaved himself nor *I shaved him himself works).

[Object coreference is perhaps also marginally possible with object predicates, as in ?I consider him himself, but that is so marginal I doubt I’ve ever even seen such a construction in real life, and I’m not sure I’d consider it well-formed if I did.]

@JanusBahsJacquet But again, I think such disambiguatives are always marked by stress, and there's obviously no need for disambiguation in "to be beside oneself", as there's no one else you can be beside in the relevant sense (which is why it would be weird to stress "oneself").

Also subject coreference is not required when the disambiguative is the object of a preposition, as here, e.g. I love you for yourself. So if OP's -self examples do require it, as seems to be the case, they must be reflexive.

@TKR Hmm, good point about PPs. It can even be just about acceptable to not have any overt coreference at all there: He did it for themselves is at least reasonably ok to me (= he’s a member of a group and did something for that group, not for another group). It seems the only context where subject coreference is syntactically required is in non-embedded apposition, in which context it is required for both reflexives and disambiguatives. Elsewhere, it may be semantically required, depending on the specific construction.

He did it for themselves?  Is that even idiomatic in English? He did it for them.

Yeah, I personally wouldn't accept "He did it for themselves" even though the other edge cases are at least vaguely plausible for me. I could only express that by a paraphrase like "for his team" or "for himself and everyone with him".
